# Can this heat damage to Silestone countertop be (easily) repaired?

Tags: kitchen-counters, countertops, damage, quartz

We cooked some meat in a sous vide for Christmas dinner. Unfortunately we must have forgotten to place a trivet underneath the stock pot we used and so there appears to be some heat damage to our Silestone countertop.

[image: Silestone heat damage]

The area of interest is the lighter grey circle in the center of the photo. I assume it is heat damage because it matches the location of the stock pot while it was in use and is roughly the same size. The sous vide was set to 137F and was used for approximately 3hrs.

Given the temperature and duration, would this affect the stone itself, or is it perhaps just the sealant that has been damaged? Is there any hope of a quick fix to restore this to match the rest of the countertop surface?

Comment: pour a puddle of water on the area and let it sit ... 137 F should not damage stone, but it will dry it out if the stone is porous

Comment: Try some of the polish that you're 'supposed' to be using every year but nobody does anyway. [Like this](https://store.countertopspecialty.com/Stone-Care-Topical-Granite-and-Marble-Polish-1-QT-p182.html) but it "Will not repair etching or excessively dull countertops. To repair dull spots from chemical etching use the Etch Remover / Marble Polishing product." (I've no affiliation, and I've never had to work with Silestone which has resin in it, and if it's more than just the polish I'd assume you'd have to grind it down or use several products in succession).

Comment: perhaps try bleach on the rest of the countertop.